# node server, [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Tags: node.js

**src/app.ts**

```
async function startServer() {
  const app = express();
  await require('./loaders').default({
    expressApp: app
  });
  const httpsServer = https.createServer({
    ca: [
      fs.readFileSync('files/ssl/AAACertificateServices.crt'),
      fs.readFileSync('files/ssl/SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt')
    ],
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('files/ssl/api.coinexchaPvt.crt')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('files/ssl/api_coinexcha_com.crt')),
  }, app);

  httpsServer.listen(config.port, () => {
    Logger.info(`
          ################################################
          ️  Server listening on port: ${config.port} ️
          ################################################
        `);
  }).on('error', err => {
    Logger.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
}
startServer();
```

**package.json**

```
"main": "src/app.ts",
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc",
  "start": "nodemon",
 }
```

my server running correctly but after some time, unexpected clean exit occurs and server stop listening.

how to handle clean exit and start listening again or debug this issue.

**Thanks**

Comment: What do you mean by a "clean exit"?

Comment: nodemon is showing this line: "[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart",
and server has stopped running

Comment: I don't know what `./loaders` does, but if you have a "clean exit" something in your code tells your http listener to stop listening or even exit your process. May also be some exception that causes the http listener to stop but is caught later on. Can you pin the stopping on a certain request or timeframe?

Comment: there is no any timeframe or certain request,
server was live on friday, when I check today then server has stopped listening, I started server again in morning and server is working proper till now, 
I do not know what happening to server sometimes, suddenly stopped listening.

Comment: ./loaders, I am using bulletproof node (Typescript), in loaders all Dependency Injector loads

Comment: try adding a `.on("close", () => {})` eventhandler, so that you can at least see whether `.close()` was called from somewhere. If there are no errors or uncaught exceptions in the console, I cannot imagine any other reason for a "clean exit" than `process.exit(0)` or `server.close()` being called from somewhere.